# Linking a sharepoint list to Excel Online

Tags: list, excel

I have a list in sharepoint. I've figured out how to extract it to Excel, and create a data connection. My question is, how do I extract it and create a data connection to Excel online/Excel in sharepoint?

Is there a way to merge queries in Excel in sharepoint? For example, merging multiple lists together?

I'm brand new to sharepoint, so I apologize if the questions have easy answers - I've spent the last few hours googling everything I could, but still have massive holes in my knowledge.